# Managing absence of current location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new to the objective C programming and I am in a position where I need to create an iPhone App really quickly. I am using XCode 4.2

I have found a method to get the user country (using NSLocale)

I assume that the application will ask the user if he wants to use his/her current location for that?

if the user says "don t allow" how can we manage that , what are the functions that can be used ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Core Location methods automatically handles user permission, if that's what you're asking. If the user says he doesn't want his location to be used, well, handle it the way you want : display an error message, of it is crucial to your app, display an alert saying how location is crucial to your app, and exit it. Or something else, it's up to you.

You can check if the location services are enabled system-wise with `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]`. For your app only, when getting the location fails, the `- locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didFailWithError:(NSError*)error` message is sent to the location managed delegate. You can check the error domain/code to have more details

Comment: how can I say if (user did not want to allow sharing his location) ?

Comment: You can check if the location services are enabled system-wise with `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]`. For your app only, when getting the location fails, the `- locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didFailWithError:(NSError*)error` message is sent to the location managed delegate. You can check the error domain/code to have more details